# Likelihoods combining multiple latent GPs in GPflow

Tags: gpflow

I am trying to implement Variational Heteroscedastic Gaussian Process Regression in GPFlow.

My idea is to use the Variational Sparse Gaussian Process model (gpflow.models.SVGP) with a custom built Likelihood which expresses the density of **y** given two independend GPs **f**, **g**:

p(**y**|**f**, **g**) = N(y | **f**, t(**g**) )
Where t(·) is some transformation to make **g** positive (currently using `tf.nn.softplus`).

To make this work, I am setting `model.num_latent` to 2, but will implement the Likelihood in such a way that `logp`, `conditional_mean`, `conditional_variance` method only output tensors with shape (N, 1). Below is my current implementation:

```py
from gpflow.likelihoods import Likelihood
from gpflow.decors import params_as_tensors

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions


class HeteroscedasticGaussian(Likelihood):
    r"""
    When using this class, num_latent must be 2.
    It does not support multi-output (num_output will be 1)
    """
    def __init__(self, transform=tf.nn.softplus, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.transform = transform

    @params_as_tensors
    def Y_given_F(self, F):
        mu = tf.squeeze(F[:, 0])
        sigma = self.transform(tf.squeeze(F[:, 1]))
        Y_given_F = tfd.Normal(mu, sigma)
        return Y_given_F

    @params_as_tensors
    def logp(self, F, Y):
        return self.Y_given_F(F).log_prob(Y)

    @params_as_tensors
    def conditional_mean(self, F):
        return self.Y_given_F(F).mean()

    @params_as_tensors
    def conditional_variance(self, F):
        return self.Y_given_F(F).variance()
```

My doubt is how to make the method `variational_expectations` work with what would be a double integral over d**f** d**g**. I intend to use Gauss-Hermite quadrature, but I could not understand how to perform this double integral with the `ndiagquad`.

Is it as simple as calling

```py
ndiagquad(self.logp, self.num_gauss_hermite_points, Fmu, Fvar, Y=Y)
```

??

EDIT:

Some MWE, using the implementation of `variational_expectations` from the base class `Likelihood`.

```py
import gpflow as gpf
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

N = 1001
M = 100

X = np.linspace(0, 4*np.pi, N)[:, None]
F = np.sin(X)
G = np.cos(X)
E = np.logaddexp(0, G) * np.random.normal(size=(N,1))
Y = F + E
Z_idx = np.random.choice(N, M, replace=False)

kernel = gpf.kernels.SquaredExponential(input_dim=1)
likelihood = HeteroscedasticGaussian()
likelihood.num_gauss_hermite_points = 11
model = gpf.models.SVGP(
    X=X, Z=X[Z_idx], Y=Y,
    kern=kernel, 
    likelihood=likelihood, 
    num_latent=2
)

# This method will call 
# model.likelihood.variational_expectations(...)
# internally
model.compute_log_likelihood()
```

I am getting the following error message:

```py
InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [1001,11] vs. [2002]
     [[{{node SVGP-bdd79b25-24/Normal/log_prob/standardize/sub}}]]
```

Which I believe has something to do with **f**, **g** being stacked on top of each other (shape [2002] = 2*N, with N = 1001), and Gauss-Hermite Points (11) being generated for only one Dimension for each observation (N = 1001), otherwise we would have a shape [1001, 11, 11] or [1001, 121=11^2].

All help appreciated.

Comment: I've edited your MWE to actually have heteroscedastic noise! With the changes from the answer below, you can optimise the model and then plot the two latent GPs against F and G and see that it learns both mean and noise variance very well.

Answer (score 1):

You were very close - we did implement multi-dimensional quadrature in `ndiagquad` exactly for this use-case, though it needs to be called slightly differently. It would be good to have it work such that what you wrote works out of the box. But unfortunately it's not completely trivial to find a design that works both for actual multi-output regression, single-output likelihoods with several latent GPs, and the combination of the two! `ndiagquad` expects *tuples* (or lists) for `Fmu` and `Fvar` to indicate that you want multi-dimensional integration -- this preserves backwards-compatibility for **f** having shape (N, L) when you want to predict multiple outputs with `Y` also having shape (N, L).

So you've got to write the code slightly differently. This version works with your MWE:

```py
from gpflow.likelihoods import Likelihood
from gpflow.decors import params_as_tensors

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_probability as tfp
tfd = tfp.distributions


class MultiLatentLikelihood(Likelihood):
    def __init__(self, num_latent=1, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.num_latent = num_latent

    def _transform(self, F):
        return [F[:, i] for i in range(self.num_latent)]

    def predict_mean_and_var(self, Fmu, Fvar):
        return super().predict_mean_and_var(self._transform(Fmu), self._transform(Fvar))

    def predict_density(self, Fmu, Fvar, Y):
        return super().predict_density(self._transform(Fmu), self._transform(Fvar), Y)

    def variational_expectations(self, Fmu, Fvar, Y):
        return super().variational_expectations(self._transform(Fmu), self._transform(Fvar), Y)

class HeteroscedasticGaussian(MultiLatentLikelihood):
    r"""
    When using this class, num_latent must be 2.
    It does not support multi-output (num_output will be 1)
    """
    def __init__(self, transform=tf.nn.softplus, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(num_latent=2, **kwargs)
        self.transform = transform

    @params_as_tensors
    def Y_given_F(self, F, G):
        mu = tf.squeeze(F)
        sigma = self.transform(tf.squeeze(G))
        Y_given_F = tfd.Normal(mu, sigma)
        return Y_given_F

    @params_as_tensors
    def logp(self, F, G, Y):
        return self.Y_given_F(F, G).log_prob(Y)

    @params_as_tensors
    def conditional_mean(self, F, G):
        return self.Y_given_F(F, G).mean()

    @params_as_tensors
    def conditional_variance(self, F, G):
        return self.Y_given_F(F, G).variance()
```

I separated the boiler-plate code in its own class, `MultiLatentLikelihood`, to make it clearer what is generic and what is specific to a heteroscedastic Gaussian.

Maybe we should put both the `MultiLatentLikelihood` and examples into GPflow - if you would be up for it, why not add this to GPflow and make a Pull Request on github.com/GPflow/GPflow ? Would be happy to review it.

Also, the GPflow tutorials contain [a notebook demonstrating how to deal with heteroscedastic noise](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/doc/source/notebooks/advanced/varying_noise.ipynb) in case you hadn't come across it - but it doesn't allow you to learn a latent GP to model the noise variance. So again, I think it'd be great if you wanted to extend the notebook with this example ("Demo 3") and make a Pull Request for your amendments :)

Comment: Hey STJ! I will check the code you supplied and work with the notebook.
If everything works well, I will try to make the Pull Request.